# unable to resolve class groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

Tags: groovy, template-engine

I am trying to get some hands-on experience about template engine using groovy. Referring to the [official document](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_streamingtemplateengine)

Below is the code snipped that I am trying to execute, but got an error saying "**unable to resolve class groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine**".

```
def text = '''\
    dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname},
    We <% if (accepted) out.print ' are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %> 
    to inform you, '$title' was ${accepted ? 'accepted' : 'declined' }. 
    '''

def Template = new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)
def binding = [
    firstname : "raghu",
    lastname : "lokineni",
    accepted : "true",
    title : "groovy"
]

string response = Template.make(binding)
println "${response}"
```

**I have further added the following code to resolve the error but no use**.

```
import groovy.text.*
```

Can someone explain me what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just downloaded latest groovy and executed this script and it works. Just that 'string' changed to def.

Answer (score 2):

add `groovy-templates` dependencies in `build.gradle` solved my problem.

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-templates', version: '2.5.7'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use import with just `new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)` or `new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)` without import statement. Check that `string response` is `String response`: string class is uppercased. It works fine for me, so.

Also make sure, that dependencies in your project is added for groovy libraries like `compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14')` in gradle, for example. Seems your program can`t find groovy libraries.

Comment: `StreamingTemplateEngine` is in the library `groovy-templates`, so it's likely they just need to add this to their dependencies.  Or use `groovy-all` as you say 

Comment: I have tried those before and no use. Regarding finding of groovy libraries, I am able to execute the similar programs with SimpleTemplateEngine and GStringTemplateEngine but not with StreamingTemplateEngine. I beleive all these are under the same library. Any info on this ?